# Giving error with dot in url

Tags: .htaccess, url

i have a problem with my url, when dot comes in url it gives an 404 error.

url: http://example.com/Samsung-Galaxy-Mega-5.8

i used some code in htaccess but it doesn't work properly.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z_\-]+)/?([a-zA-Z0-9\-=&_@\.]*)$ /$1.php?$2 [QSA,L]
```

**EDIT (copied from comment):**

```
RewriteEngine on 
Options -Indexes 
#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-A-Z_]*).([a-z]*)$ 
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1.%2/$1 [L,R=301] 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show_mobile.php?bid=$1&brandname=$2 
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ show_mobile.php?bid=$2&brandname=$1
```

Comment: Show us more of your [.htaccess]. This by itself is looking for `/?` which does not exist in the example URL you gave.

Comment: here are my htaccess full codes: RewriteEngine on
Options -Indexes

#RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9-A-Z_]*).([a-z]*)$
#RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%1.%2/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


#RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ show_mobile.php?bid=$1&brandname=$2
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)$ show_mobile.php?bid=$2&brandname=$1

Answer (score 0):

I guess the following should get you going:

```
^([a-z0-9\-\.]+)\-([a-z0-9\-\.]+)$i
```

(based on the .htaccess from comment)

https://regex101.com/r/jZ9sP3/1

You didn't allow for periods and you didn't escape the hyphen inbetween the catching rules.

the tailing `i` is for case insensitive, so you don't need to do `a-zA-Z`